# TYPO3 - include sysfolder in typoscriptObjectPath and wrap with additional elements/classes

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x, typo3-8.7.x

I want to replicate this with typoscript ...

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li role="presentation"><p class="footer-header"><span class="footer-header-span">Company</span></p></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/impressum/">Impressum</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/terms-of-use/">Terms of Use</a></li>
</ul>
```

... where 'Company' is a sysfolder ...

```
Company [Sys Folder][10]
|_Home [Link]
|_Impressum [Link]
|_Terms of Use [Link]
```

... the below renders me the links

```
lib.footerlinks = HMENU
lib.footerlinks {

  special = directory
  special.value = 10

  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">|</ul>

    NO = 1
    NO {
        ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        ATagTitle.field = title
        allWrap = <li role="presentation">|</li>
    }

    CUR = 1
    CUR.ATagParams = class="active"
    CUR.allWrap = <li role="presentation">|</li>
  }

}
```

... so I get this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/impressum/">Impressum</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="/terms-of-use/">Terms of Use</a></li>
</ul>
```

But how can I add the sysfolder as the first li with the additional elements around it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve this using the property "entryLevel" but then you will need two menue levels. Try something like this:

```
lib.footerlinks = HMENU
lib.footerlinks {

  special = directory
  special.value = 10
  entryLevel = -1

  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">|</ul>

    NO = 1
    NO {
        ATagBeforeWrap = 1
        ATagTitle.field = title
        allWrap = <li role="presentation">|</li>
    }

    CUR = 1
    CUR.ATagParams = class="active"
    CUR.allWrap = <li role="presentation">|</li>
  }
  2 < .1
  2 {
    wrap >
  } 
}
```